# Gibbs Phase Rule for a Suspension

Tags: thermodynamics

How does Gibbs phase rule applies to a dilute suspension?

Gibbs phase rule:
$$F=C-P+2$$
where $F$ is the number of degree of freedom, $C$ is the number of components and $P$ is the number of phases.

I naively thought $C=2$ because there are the particles of the solvent and the particles of the solute and $P=1$ because the suspension is liquid. However in this case $F=2-1+2=3$ that is wrong because the real number of degree of freedom is 4 (for example they could be $T,P,N_{solute}, N_{solvent}$)